# How to delete/edit files created by other user?

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, apache2, amazon-ec2

I asked client to create a sub-domain and a folder for me.

He created a sub-domain and dir `ygjhazaxnv`

I only have SSH access as `mani` user.

I put files in `ygjhazaxnv` folder via `Git pull` and the owner of all these files is `mani`. So far all OK.

Now the project I configured is able to create files dynamically, whatever the files are created by my project(PHP files) has owner `ygjhazaxnv`

Now how can I delete files created by `ygjhazaxnv` user when logged in as `mani`?

I tried to own those files via `chown` but error `chown: changing ownership of ‘ABC’: Operation not permitted`

Both `ygjhazaxnv` and `root` user lies under group `www-data`

Server is Amazon EC2

Answer (score 1):

Ask the client to add `mani` to the group named `www-data` and give write permissions to that group for the whole folder.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider setting the umask for both users to 002 instead of the default (022).  This will ensure files created by both users have group writable access.